# I am new to ubuntu and i see a new thing when i shut down the computer?

Tags: 16.04

[image: first thing i see when the computer shuts down]

This is my second time to download ubuntu, and whene i  shut down the computer i see this. the computer shuts down without any problem but i just wonder why this thing appears to me and what it is.
The first time i downloaded ubuntu (the same version 16.04) i did not see that screen.
I tried to find a solution to this problem but i could not find any help about this problem.

Comment: It's not a problem.

Comment: but what is that line? and why didn't i see it the first time i downloaded ubuntu?

Comment: That output shows that the filesystem is clean. It is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things Ubuntu do when starting up, is checking your disk(s), and writes to the screen before starting the Desktop Environment. And when it shutsdown the DE, the text from startup is still there .. nothing to be worried about as @Ziazis said.